# Can ansible ping and SSH into machine but playbook fails due to "Host key verification failed" error

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have a Jenkins project which pulls and containerises changes from the given repo and then uses an Ansible playbook to deploy to the host machine/s. There are over 10 different server groups in my `/etc/ansible/hosts` file, all of which can be pinged successfully using `ansible -m ping all` and SSH'd into from the Jenkins machine.

I spun up a new VM, added it to the `hosts` file and used `ssh-copy-id` to add the Jenkins machine's public key. I received a pong from my ansible ping *and* successfully SSH'd into the machine. When the run the project I receive the following error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [my_machine]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.", "unreachable": true}
```

The Jenkins project is virtually identical with my other projects and VM is the same as my other ones.

In the end I had to add `host_key_checking = False` into my `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file but that is just a temporary fix.

Other answers online seem to show that the issue is with the SSH key but I don't believe this is true in my case as I can SSH into the machine. I would like to understand how to get rid of this error message and deploy without not checking the host key.

The remote host is in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you SSH into the machine I assume you are doing that from your account. Is that correct? If so, are you using your account to run the Ansible Playbook? Basically, the error you are getting is saying that when SSH goes to connect the key of the remote server is not in the known_hosts list. My guess is your Ansible Playbook process is running under an account that hasn't accessed the host before so the key isn't in `known_hosts`.

Comment: @MikeCoakley thanks your reply. I only use the one account and can confirm that the remote server is in `known_hosts`.

Comment: in my experience it really comes down to the key being in `known_hosts` but it does seem like you've covered your bases. Have you turned on all of the Ansible debugging? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_debug_troubleshooting.html#enabling-networking-logging-and-how-to-read-the-logfile provides good information. You might see something in there that helps move this issue further along. Maybe you could edit your question to include the debugging output for the task that is failing.

Comment: Can you please expand `~` in your question and double check that when your verify the key exist you are logged in as the same user which will run the playbook from jenkins (i.e. in general the `jenkins` user) ? For clarity, on a usual setup, the target server key should be in `/home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts` (or `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts` depending your configuration) if you intend to use host key verification.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for your reply. My `~` is `/root/.ssh`. When I `su` into the Jenkins user I can see the `known_hosts` file is the same.

Answer (score 0):

SSH to a remote host will verify the key in the remote host. And if ssh to a new machine, there will question ask you whether to add / trust the key. If you choose "Yes" the key will be saved in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts.

The message "Host key verification failed" implies that the key file of the remote host is not found / changed in the machine that run the Ansible script.

I normally resolve this problem by issuing a ssh to the remote host and add the key to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raymond. The remote host is in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. I've even tried deleting it and then going through the process of choosing "Yes" when connecting again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to disable the host SSH key check in the Jenkins Job Configuration

[image]